# Json data not displaying properly

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get values from the json data and display the same in the row. But the problem i am facing is I am not able to display any data. Here's the url from where i am taking the values You can click in the link to check the values .[You can click here to view the response of the json daya](https://joloapi.com/api/findplan.php?userid=Akash4196&key=253258928289764&opt=28&cir=1&typ=TUP&max=&amt=)

Now here's the code

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init(); 
$timeout = 30;
$myurl = "https://joloapi.com/api/findplan.php?userid=Akash4196&key=253258928289764&opt=28&cir=1&typ=TUP&max=&amt=";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $myurl);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$jsonxx = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_error = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$someArray = json_decode($jsonxx, true);
if (count($someArray) > 0) {
echo "<table><thead><tr>
<th>Detail</th>
<th>Amount (Rs.)</th>
<th>Validity (days)</th>
</tr></thead><tbody>";
foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
 echo " <tr><td>" .$value["Detail"] . "</td> <td>" .$value["Amount"] . "
</td> <td>" .$value["Validity"] . "</td> </tr>";
 }
 echo "</tbody></table><br/>";

 }else{
 echo"No offer details available for this category";
 }
  ?>
```

if the link is not working because of IP Address error please check the screenshot

[Please View the image for the response of the URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR8pC.png)

Comment: so what is you are getting? where is the problem?? can you post your output? are you trying to display like the one in picture? or something else

Comment: I am getting an output "No offer details available for this category"